# rails4 // pluralize do pluralize when count is at 0

Tags: string, ruby-on-rails-4, pluralize

I have a big problem with pluralize : when 0, it does pluralize the word

```
pluralize(@posts.size,"post")
```

if @posts.size equals 0 :

```
0 posts
```

if @posts.size equals 1 :

```
1 post
```

if @posts.size equals 2 or more :

```
n posts
```

As it should not add an s when 0 by default, I'm lost. Is there anyone seeing what's wrong right here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use another method for this :

In my view:

```rb
= t('counts.offers', count: project.nb_offers)
# t() is a shortcut for I18n.translate
```

The first parameter is the path in your file locale file, the second is the thing you want to count.

Then, in your config/locales/xx.yml (fr in my case):

```rb
fr:
  counts:
    offers:
      zero: 0 offre
      one: 1 offre
      other: "%{count} offres"
```

So I don't have to create a new config file, simply use locales

Answer (score 3):

Any number not 1 is considered plural. Instead of saying:

```
You have 0 posts.
```

the correct English sentence would be:

```
You do not have any posts.
```

Take a look at [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/13075) and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/38310).

Edit: Your request is fairly large and may not be possible for anyone (atleast for me) to succinctly put it in a single post. I would rather suggest you read through Internationalization (popularly called i18n) doc.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

Basically, there are 2 things, `Translations` and `Inflectors`.

Inflectors are rules defining how a string or a pattern substitutes into singular or plural or if it's uncountable. Example, plural for `is` is `are` is defined as an inflector.

I18n helps you define locale specified humanized text for a string. If you see in your Rails project, inside `config` folder, you will see a folder called `locales`, which contains single `YAML` file for each locale. Such humanized text for locales are called translations.

`pluralize` is a function that is defined at 3 places:

1. Inside Inflector module.
2. As a `String`'s instance method.
3. As a Helper method inside `ActionView`.

Usually in Rails, we call the helper method, which may make a call to String's method which in turns calls the Inflector's method.

You try adding following code inside `config/initializers/filename.rb` and trying running again:

```
module ActionView
  module Helpers
    module TextHelper
      def pluralize(count, singular, plural = nil)
        "#{count || 0} " + ([0, 1, '0', '1'].include?(count) ? singular : (plural || singular.pluralize))
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This will return `0 post` but for the default locale only which is `en`. If you wish to do it for a specific locale, call the String pluralize function with selected locale and pass it to above function as 3 argument. Example, for `fr` locale, you may try something like:

```
pluralize 0, "post", "post".pluralize(:fr) # => will return for fr locale
```

Ask more questions here at SO and let experts explain in more detail.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: my bad. But am french, and we do not pluralize when zero. How to handle it ?

Comment: Do you want to do it only for French locale or for all locales, including English?

Comment: Well; if you could teach me how to handle it all; I guess it'd be perfect !

Comment: Thanks for not just some explanations! Gonna look further

Comment: @Ben You are not alone, as a non-native English speaker I also thought this way which is annoying at first but I get over it now.

Comment: What does .Pluralize() return for negative numbers??

Comment: In the end how can we tell `pluralize` to add no s when called with 0? `pluralize('document', 0) // 0 document` with `config.i18n.default_locale = :fr`? Only by extending `TextHelper`? Doesn't feel very clean...